# The DMA support is needed to implement a device type interrupt driven?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, cpu-architecture, dma

From what I understand, interrupt-driven I / O and DMA are two separate mechanisms, but I need to answer this question. I think the answer is no for the fact that it is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a device uses DMA (Direct Memory Access), it is able to read or/and write directly from/to the main memory.
If a device can generate interrupts, it is able to notify the CPU that it requires attention.
So, DMA and interrupts are principally completely independent.
They can of course be combined, e.g. a device can notify the CPU that it has finished a DMA.
So, you are right, the answer is NO.

Comment: @fedegovo: If you find the answer OK, you should accept it, just to close the question. If not: What is missing?